# Gatling exec function returned by function

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm working with Gatling using Scala IDE (Eclipse Luna) and I ran into this issue that I would like to understand.

I have this function

```
import io.gatling.core.session.Session
import io.gatling.core.Predef._

object Predef {
    def justDoIt(param: String): Session => Session = s => s.set("some", param)
}
```

And I'm trying to use it that way

```
val testScenario1 = scenario("Test")
    .exec(justDoIt("hello world"))

val testScenario2 = scenario("Test")
    .exec(justDoIt("hello world")(_))
```

For some reason, only the latter compiles. The former is complaining about the overload not applicable on argument of type `Session => Session`.

I would like to understand the difference between those two lines and why is the first one failing to compile.

I also did the following test and both syntax seems to be doing the same thing:

```
scala> def hello(fn: String => String) = fn("Hello")
hello: (fn: String => String)String

scala> def message(name: String): String => String = greeting => s"$greeting $name"
message: (name: String)String => String

scala> hello(message("world"))
res1: String = Hello world

scala> hello(message("world")(_))
res2: String = Hello world
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According do [docs](http://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/):

> exec can also be passed an Expression function.

... which is [alias for](http://gatling.io/docs/current/session/expression_el/#expression):

```
Session => Validation[T]
```

Also pay attention to this excerpt from the first link:

> For those who wonder how the plumbing works and how you can return a Session instead of Validation[Session] in the above examples, that’s thanks to an implicit conversion.

Now, with that info you can see that in the first case you are passing to `exec` something of type `Session => Session` (for which there is no implicit conversion to `Expression[Session]` exists in scope) and you get compile error.

In the second case you're using placeholder/partial application for:

```
justDoIt("hello world")(_)
```

... which is equivalent of:

```
x => justDoIt("hello world")(x)
```

... which can benefit from implicit conversion of the return value (from `Session` to `Validation[Session]`) and, as a result whole expression gets inferred to be conforming `Expression[Session]` which is just what `exec` requires.

**UPDATE:** here is the [relevant implicit](https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/4bd63f26bdbf3bbb88fc20b68eacf0caf9af4082/gatling-core/src/main/scala/io/gatling/core/ValidationImplicits.scala#L49) that does the conversion.

**UPDATE 2:** to make your original example work you can simply change the return type of `justDoIt` like this (to benefit from implicit conversion):

```
def justDoIt(param: String): Session => Validation[Session] = s => s.set("some", param)
```

Comment: Thank you Eugene. I'm Gatling core commiter and that's the perfect answer.